# mod rewrite: handling sub domains, top level domains and query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to redirect any URL stat starts like `[subdomain.]example.TLD[/?query_string]` to `example.org[/?query_string]`

Following rule sets each are working, but not in combination.
I.e. www.example.com => example.org 
example.com/?query_string => example.org/?query_string

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.org
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.org
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one rule as QUERY_STRING is automatically copied over to after redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: After the change: redirecting domains works, but QUERY_STRING is still lost.

Comment: QUERY_STRING is't lost by above rule, try in a different browser.

Comment: As it is still lost, it seems a superior .htaccess is causing this. I'll check.

Comment: A superior .htaccess was causing the trouble. Thanks!